# Using with statement in python

Tags: python

Hey guys am trying to use the `with` statement in my code..Since am new to python i just wrote to code to understand the working of `with` statement..My code

```
class Employee:
    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary


c = Employee("blah",1)
c.empCount = ['aad']




class Subin(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary


    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self ,type):
        print 'ok'


    def babe(self):
        with c.empCount as b:
            return 0

b = Subin("sds",1)
b.babe()
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/dfg", line 38, in <module>
    b.babe()
  File "C:/Python27/dfg", line 33, in babe
    with c.empCount as b:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Can you guys tell me why this is happening?

Comment: That's not what the `with` keyword does. Read the [PEP-343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). Please also [edit] your question and fix the indention of your code.

Comment: Please, try to properly format your code. It's totally unreadable as of now.

Comment: Your first problem is that the thing you're trying to use as a context manager with the `with` statement is not a context manager at all - it's `c.empCount`, which is a *list*. `Subin` on the other hand could (almost) be a context manager, so you'd do something like `with Subin("foo",1) as s:`. But for that to have any chance of working, you'd need to fix the signature of the [`__exit__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__)  first.

Comment: @LukasGraf doesn it work with lists or only with classes ??

Comment: @Tichodroma is this only used with classes ..can i use it with lists or functions inside the employee class ??

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Python code is not "free form". If your indentation is incorrect, it will not compile or run. Cutting and pasting your code into an interpreter will show you that.

Secondly, you're using the `with` statement wrongly. It's not the `Subin` class that should work as a context manager (with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods although the latter has the wrong number of arguments) but the `c.empCount` object which is a list here and therefore won't work.

The with statement is described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) in the official documentation some examples are provided.

I'd recommend that you play with basic python a little more before trying out context managers.

Comment: doesnt it work with lists ??

Comment: A list is not a context manager.

Comment: what about the functions inside a class ??..is it a context manager ??

Comment: A function (inside or outside a class) is not a context manager.